# Example NetworkUsage Android Code Crashes On Startup?

Tags: android, crash, sample

I am trying to run the example application in the *networkusage.zip* file on the *Android Developers* website (location: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html).

I have not made any changes to the code whatsoever. However, it crashes immediately on startup. I have tried setting a breakpoint in the `onCreate` method of the main activity, but it never gets there....just crashes right away.

I am just starting with *Android*, but I been able to complete other training sessions and run other example apps, so I believe my configuration works. I am running *Windows 7*, with *Eclipse Juno* and the very latest *JDK* and *Android SDK/ADT* (both downloaded about a week ago).

I am using an emulator targeting *Android 4.1 (API 16)*.

The emulator shows a messages that says `Unfortunately, NetWork Usage has stopped working.`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 3):

In `AndroidManifest.xml` file, for this project, substitute absolute `android:name` for `NetworkActivity` with relative one.

In other words, change this line:

```
android:name="com.example.networkusage.NetworkActivity"
```

to look like this:

```
android:name=".NetworkActivity"
```

The problem was that `NetworkActivity` is not in `com.example.networkusage` (as was in `AndroidManifest.xml` file), but in `com.example.android.networkusage` package. Thus, Android couldn't find the class on runtime.